# Error Uploading image in laravel when deployed on IIS server

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, iis

[image: The errors getting on the file upload]

On file upload iam getting these errors. Laravel application is deployed on IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is a notice. It happens when your php.ini has the wrong upload_tmp_dir path.

To resolve the error make sure the set upload folder path is correct and it exists. then assign the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to that folder.